# how do I break an equation when there is \left and \right involved?

Tags: latex, equations

I am using an align environment, and at some point I am interested in breaking an equation to the next line. The problem is that this equation includes a `\left` and `\right`, so when I try to break it using `\\`, I get an error. Any ideas?

For example, the following wouldn't compile:

```
\begin{align}
\left(4+5+6+ \\
4 + 6 +2 \right)
\end{align}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe more details? It's difficult to guess what's going on. How to break?

Comment: Equation examples and wanted results would help to `Break on Through (To the Other Side)`.

Comment: this belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\right.` at the end of the first line and `\left.` at the beginning of the second line to function as placeholders for the matching `\right` wihtout any symbol shown.

So exactly like this:

```
\begin{align}
\left( 4+5+6+ \right. \\
\left. 4 + 6 +2 \right)
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\left` and `\right`, you can specify the size of the brackets with `\Big`, `\big`, `\bigg`, etc so that you do not have that kind of problem. See [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses).

The code you've given will be like this:

```
\begin{align}
\big(4+5+6+ \\
4 + 6 +2 \big)
\end{align}
```